# How to get the Indexes of all columns In a Single Row using Selenium WebDriver and C#?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, test-automation-framework

For single web element in that row i got index..for  multiple column in a single row how to get the index:

```
IWebElement colelement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='grdBooking']//table//tr/
th[contains(text(),'Case#')]"));
String colidx = colelement.GetAttribute("idx"); 
Console.WriteLine("Colelement index is =" + colidx);
```

Comment: Can you add your table structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of multiple column elements from a single row using For or For-each loop.

First get the column count by using .size() method and use for loop for getting all the index of all elements from the column.